# How do I say "I own myself" in Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation

I am trying to grasp the difference between "I" and "myself" in Latin.

How would the phrase "I own myself" translate to Latin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to my mind, you could just use `me ipsum` if you are male and `me ipsam` if you are female for `myself`, whereas for `I`, you could just use the first person singular in the predicate or, if you want to emphasize it some more, `ego`.
Therefore, you could translate your sentence thus:

> (Ego) me ipsum/-am possideo.

Best regards,
Klaus

Comment: I edited *possido* to *possideo*, since I'm pretty sure that's what you meant.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you're totally right.

Comment: An alternative to _possideo_ is _habeo_. As in, _animus habet cuncta neque ipse habetur_ ("the spirit/mind dominates everything and nothing dominates it").

Answer (score -1):

In addition to Klaus's wonderful answer, you could also use Suus-a-um. As in, "Ego suum possideo." I own my own (self).